# gnome: what is the name of this bar?

Tags: gnome

This certainly is a bad question, but I have this window on the bottom left corner of my laptop, which contains icons of a few active applications (here kgpg and hexchat).

[image: Unknown window]

I cannot find this window on my desktop (debian as well) and it looks like I cannot use kgpg without that bar (it launches reduced).
However I did not find any good search term for google to find which package I need to install or where to activate the needed option to display this bar.

I tried to identify a PID with 'xprop' but it returns 'XdndProxy(WINDOW): window id # 0xe0000a' which does not look very informative.

Here is a full screenshot of the bar:
[image: Full screenshot]

Comment: I think it would be much nicer if you included a full screenshot, rather than a tiny bar. By looking at the picture I couldn't even tell you where that bar is located on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is refereed to as the legacy "tray" icons.

According to this [source](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/gnome-316-released-with-new.html) *As for legacy "tray" icons, they can still be accessed in GNOME 3.16 and they are displayed in a "drawer" that uses autohide in the bottom left corner of the screen.*

It appears that this is no different than the large icon bar that used to be located on the left hand side of the screen.

[image]

Comment: I cannot upvote (yet). Now I have a name to search for, thank you very much !

Comment: @user2245644 that's ok that you can't upvote. I tried looking for more information on it before posting, but that's the best I could find. If you find something more detailed, feel free to edit the answer and add to it.